# Is there any native panorama SDK, especially for Titanium?

Tags: titanium

I am looking for a panorama SDK for native mobile app. but I haven't found any one. could someone give me a clue?

I am planning to use this SDK in Titanium project. so either native or Titanium SDK is OK.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe this one? https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/japanoview/ But there are a few others out there I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mobile development, there's no need to implement another SDK for "panorama", just use WebView and then include the "panorama web url". That's it!

example: http://yun.kujiale.com/design/3FO4KBFUDDEK/show